# How to insert a new dictionary to the deepest layer of nested dictionary?

Tags: python

Assume there is a dictionary as following. When I get a new dictionary, I want to insert it to the deepest layers.

```
d = {
    'text': 'Layer 0',
    'child': {
        'text': 'Layer 1',
        'child': {
            'text': 'Layer 2',
            'sibling': {
                'text': 'Layer 3',
            }
        }
    }
}

new_dict = {
    'text': 'Layer 4',
}

d['child']['child']['sibling']['child'] = new_dict
```

This is my code but it will overwrite the second layers of dictionary after call it twice. How to insert a new dictionary to the deepest layer of nested dictionary?

```
def nested(current_dict, new_dict, name):
  for key in ('child', 'sibling'):
    if key in current_dict:
      current_dict = nested(current_dict[key], new_dict, name)
  else:
    current_dict[name] = new_dict
  return current_dict
```

Comment: How many keys in total an atomic dictionary can have in your case? 3? (text, child, sibling)

Comment: also, what is name ?

Comment: @Ragnar It accept 3 keys (text, child, sibling), but child and sibling won't exist at the same layer. The new dictionary will be add to child if there is no child and sibling in current layer. Thank you.

Comment: Does this means that it will either have child or sibling but not both at the same time in the same layer?

Comment: @Ragnar Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```py
def nested(current_dict, new_dict, name):
  key_in_dict = None
  for key in ('child', 'sibling'):
    if key in current_dict:
      key_in_dict = key
      break
  if key_in_dict is not None:
     nested(current_dict[key_in_dict], new_dict, name)
  else:
    current_dict[name] = new_dict
```

It will insert your new dictionary where you want it.

Comment: @kolin , is this giving you the desired output? If so, then you can accept this as answer.